# HP UFT operation retrieve DataTable.Value failed. The column <module> does not exist

Tags: excel, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to get data from an imported Excel file. This file contains only one sheet with some values.

Somehow I can not select a specific value, no matter what i try I always get an error:

[HP UFT ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olXMa.png)

This is my Code so far:

```
Datatable.Importsheet "C:\Temp\test.xlsx",1,Global
row = Datatable.GetSheet(1).GetRowCount

MsgBox row

DataTable.SetCurrentRow(1)
ID_Number = Datatable.Value("Module", 1) 

MsgBox("Erstes Feld ist: " & ID_Number)
```

I am sure that the Field exists in the Excel and that it is written right.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Datatable.Importsheet "C:\Temp\test.xlsx",1,Global` to `Datatable.Importsheet "C:\Temp\test.xlsx",1,1` to actually import the excel sheet into Global sheet on data table. If you debug, you will notice that the existing data is being pasted in the Action sheet.